# Configure Fluent Nhibernate to load interface implementation based on database value

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How can I configure Fluent Nhibernate so that it knows how to load an interface implementation based on a value stored in the database?

Example:

Database:

```
[calculators]
id: int
value_a: int
value_b: int
chosen_algorithm: string
```

Class:

```
class Calculator
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ValueA { get; set; }
    public int ValueB { get; set; }
    public IAlgorithm Solver { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here's how I resolved it:

```
class CalculatorMap : ClassMap<Calculator>
{
   ...
   References<ConcreteAlgorithmeClass>(x => x.Solver);
}
```